# Do SQL bind parameters affect performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql

Suppose I have a table called `Projects` with a column called `Budget` with a standard B-Tree index.  The table has 50,000 projects, and only 1% of them have a Budget of over one million.  If I ran the SQL Query:

```
SELECT * From Projects WHERE Budget > 1000000;
```

The planner will use an index range scan on `Budget` to get the rows off the heap table.  However, if I use the query:

```
SELECT * From Projects WHERE Budget > 50;
```

The planner will most likely do a sequential scan on the table, as it will know this query will end up returning most or all rows anyway and there's no reason to load all the pages of the index into memory.

Now, let's say I run the query:

```
SELECT * From Projects WHERE Budget > :budget;
```

Where `:budget` is a bind parameter passed into my database.  From what I've read, the query as above will be cached, and no data on cardinality can be inferred.  In fact, most databases will just assume an even distribution and the cached query plan will reflect that.  This surprised me, as usually when you read about the benefits of bind parameters it's on the subject of preventing SQL injection attacks.

Obviously, this could *improve* performance if the resulting query plan would be the same, as a new plan wouldn't have to be compiled, but could also *hurt* performance if the values of `:budget` greatly varied.

**My Question:** Why are bind parameters not resolved *before* the query plan is generated and cached?  Shouldn't modern databases strive to generate the best plan for the query, which should mean looking at the value for each parameter and getting accurate index stats?

*Note:* This question probably doesn't apply to mySql as mySql doesn't cache SQL plans.  However, I'm interested in why this is the case on Postgres, Oracle and MS SQL.

Comment: maybe I missed the point, but if the db had to know the bind values themselves to decide the optimization/execution plan, then wouldn't this amount to a hard parse?

Comment: `The planner will [...] know this query will end up returning most or all rows anyway` - Is this true? Do those databases maintain some kind of histogram of index values on which they can base decisions taking lookup values into account?

Comment: @AndreKR - Correct.  Most any modern database keeps statistics on table cardinality..

Comment: Yes, but you need more than just the cardinality to know how many more rows `Budget > 1000000` will return than `Budget > 50` before executing the query.

Comment: @AndreKR - Correct.  Typically it stores statistics such as number of distinct values, most common values, histogram of the data, and correlation (with respect of position in the table).  You should check out [Use The Index, Luke](http://use-the-index-luke.com/) - It goes over this sort of thing in detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This surprised me, as usually when you read about the benefits of bind parameters it's on the subject of preventing SQL injection attacks.

Don't confuse **parameterized queries** with **prepared statements**.  Both offer parameterization, but prepared statements offer the additional caching of the query plan.

> Why are bind parameters not resolved before the query plan is generated and cached?

Because sometimes generating the query plan is an expensive step.  Prepared statements allow you to amortize the cost of query planning.

However, if all you're looking for is SQL injection protection, don't use prepared statements.  Use parameterized queries.

For example, in PHP, you can use http://php.net/pg_query_params to execute a parameterized query WITHOUT caching the query plan; meanwhile http://php.net/pg_prepare and http://php.net/pg_execute are used to cache a plan for a prepared statement and later execute it.

Edit: [9.2 apparently changes the way prepared statements are planned](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/release-9-2.html#AEN111314)

Comment: Ah, then it appears it would be up to the developer to use a parameterized query and *not* a prepared statement if the parameter values were likely to result in a totally different execution plan (like not using an index to scan a million rows heh)..  I believe this answers my question!

Comment: am I correct in stating that Postgres will never cache an execution plan *unless* you specifically use the `PREPARE` keyword?

Comment: I believe certain methods in your client library will cause execution plan caching without the PREPARE keyword.  `pg_prepare` (php) and `PQprepare` ([libpq](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-PQPREPARE)) being examples of this.

Comment: It seems Postgres is unique in the fact it even has a *PREPARE* statement.  MS SQL and Oracle *only* allow this through API calls.

Comment: @MikeChristensen In PostgreSQL the lower-level APIs use protocol-level equivalents to `PREPARE` too. I know PgJDBC does. Somewhat confusingly a `PreparedStatement` in PgJDBC is initially executed as a parameterized query without actually using a server-side prepared statement until prepareThreshold is passed. Very odd. BTW, *prepared statements* can affect performance too, especially prior to 9.2 where they'd sometimes choose very bad query plans when they didn't know the value of bind parameters.

Comment: @CraigRinger - Does Postgres 9.2 *peek* at parameter values like Oracle does then?

Comment: From [the 9.2 changelog](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/release-9-2.html#AEN111314): `Now, the planner attempts to generate custom plans for specific parameter values. A generic plan will only be used after custom plans have repeatedly proven to provide no benefit. This change should eliminate the performance penalties formerly seen from use of prepared statements `

Answer (score 7):

For Oracle specifically, it depends.

For quite some time (at least 9i), Oracle has supported bind variable peeking.  That means that the first time a query is executed, the optimizer peeks at the value of the bind variable and bases its cardinality estimates on the value of that first bind variable.  That makes sense in cases where most of the executions of a query are going to have bind variable values that return similarly sized results.  If 99% of the queries are using small budget values, it is highly likely that the first execution will use a small value and thus the cached query plan will be appropriate for small bind variable values.  Of course, that means that when you do specify a large bind variable value (or, worse, if you get lucky and the first execution is with a large value) you'll get less than optimal query plans.

If you are using 11g, Oracle can use [adaptive cursor sharing](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/adaptive-cursor-sharing-11gr1.php).  This allows the optimizer to maintain multiple query plans for a single query and to pick the appropriate plan based on the bind variable values.  That can get rather complicated over time, though.  If you have a query with N bind variables, the optimizer has to figure out how to partition that N-dimensional space into different query plans for different bind variable values in order to figure out when and whether to re-optimize a query for a new set of bind variable values and when to simply reuse an earlier plan.  A lot of that work ends up being done at night during the nightly maintenance window in order to avoid incurring those costs during the productive day.  But that also brings up issues about how much freedom the DBA wants to give the database to evolve plans over time vs how much the DBA wants to control plans so that the database doesn't suddenly start picking a poor plan that causes some major system to slow to a crawl on a random day.

Comment: Yea, though sounds like *peeking* could be dangerous if the first value was `> 5` - Oracle would peek at the value of 5, decide not to use an index.  Then if I passed in `> 1000000`, it would use the same execution plan and scan that whole table for a few rows.  Would you concur with Frank's answer above and say using a prepared statement is simply not a good idea if parameter values were volatile?

Comment: I suspect that for direct index lookups, (`col = 5`) the cached plan will often be sufficient for all possible values assuming a normal value distribution.  In the case of an inequality (`> 5`, `> 1000000`) where the plan changes based on values, a cached plan is less likely to apply to all possible values

Comment: @MikeChristensen - Bind peeking can certainly can create issues.  If you are using an old version of Oracle (adaptive cursor sharing and 11g have been around for a while), if you want a different plan for different values, you would need to avoid using bind variables (or alter the SQL in some other way to generate a different `sql_id`).  Frequently, to Frank's point, there may be one plan that is acceptable in all cases even if not ideal-- in your example, a table scan wouldn't be optimal if the query is only returning a handful of rows but it may be acceptable.

Comment: ACS works poorly apparently : 1. Sacrifices several bad executions to kick in ! 2. Unusable with over 14 parameters (forget about IN... !) ... Hopefully Oracle will improve this in future version...